# Does unplugging a disk from linux change disk name after restart?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, dev

I had 5 disks (sda, sdb, sdc, sdd, sde)

sda is being used for root and boot. sdc,sdd and sde disks are being used by lvm.

We unmounted and unplugged the sdb, now I need to restart the server.

I am scared if device names change after restart. Maybe sdc become sdb, sdd become sdc and so on.

So am I right to be scared and panic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, block device names are not guaranteed to stay the same. You should expect them to change, although they probably won't without physical movement. If you need unchanging identifiers, try on of the several methods for [persistent block device naming](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming).

Comment: the machine is on an ESX server, will the order still change?